# Solve the inequality $\left| {\frac{2x-1}{x-1}}\right|>2$

Tags: inequality

If i remove the modulus, two inequations appear 
$$\frac{2x-1}{x-1}>2$$ and 
$$\frac{1-2x}{x-1}<2$$
The first inequality gives 
$x\in(1,\infty)$ while the second one gives $x\in(\frac 34 , 1)$

The correct answer is $x\in (\frac 34,\infty)$

I realize that it simply squaring both sides of the inequality gives the right answer, but I want to know why this method doesn’t work.

Comment: From First and Second equality , conculde $x\in (\frac 34,\infty)$

Comment: Union the two ranges and you get your 3/4<x<=infinity, ignoring the hole at 1 just like the correct answer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that the question is $$\left | \frac{2x-1}{x-1} \right |>2.~~~(*)$$
**First Method**
$$\implies \frac{2x-1}{x-1}>2~~~(1),$$  or $$ \frac{2x-1}{x-1}<-2~~~~(2).$$. 
Solving (1), we get $$\frac{2x-1}{x-1}>2 \implies \frac{1}{x-1}>0 \implies x-1>0 \implies x>1. ~~~(3).$$
Solving (2) 
$$\frac{2x-1}{x-1} <-2 \implies \frac{4x-3}{x-1}<0 \implies (4x-3)(x-1)<0 \implies\frac{3}{4} <x<1~~~~(4).$$
The net answer is union of the domains in (3) and (4). So the answer is $$x\in (3/4,1)\cup (1, \infty)~~~~(6)$$
**Second Method**

Both sides being positive we can square (*) to get
$$\frac{{2x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2}<4 \implies \frac{4x-3}{(x-1)^2}>0~~~(7)
This means $$x>3/4 ~~and~~ x\ne 1 ~~~~(8)$$ 
Which is the same as (6).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative we can proceed also as follows

$$\left| \frac{2x - 1}{x - 1} \right| > 2 \iff \left| \frac{2x - 1}{2x - 2} \right| > 1\iff \left| \frac{2x - 2+1}{2x - 2} \right| > 1\iff \left| 1+\frac{1}{2x - 2} \right| > 1$$

wich requires

$$\frac{1}{2x - 2}<-2 \quad \lor \quad \frac{1}{2x - 2}>0$$

that is since $x\neq 1$ $$\frac 34<x<1 \quad \lor \quad x>1$$