# Absolute Value Inequality!

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

### Solve the inequality
$$\left| \frac{2x - 1}{x - 1} \right| > 2.$$

I'm really confused on how to solve problems such as this. Logically I think you could take $\frac{2x-1}{x-1}>2$ and $\frac{2x-1}{x-1}<-2$. The first one gives $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$ and the second gives $x \in (-\infty,\frac34)$. However, does this mean that the answer is $x \in (-\infty,\frac34)$, because it is the stricter bound? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate how you got $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$ in the first case and $x \in (-\infty,\frac34)$ in the second case. Both look wrong to me.

Comment: Well, you get $2x-1>2x-2 \implies -1>-2$, which is always true.
For the second case, you get $2x-1<-2x+2 \implies 4x<3 \implies x<\frac34$

Comment: You are aware that the inequality reverses if multiplied with a negative number? You must take the sign of $x-1$ into account.

Comment: Food for thought: $x=0$...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve the inequality $\vert {\frac{2x-1}{x-1}}>2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387080/solve-the-inequality-vert-frac2x-1x-12)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTS2n.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Since both sides are nonnegative, we can square them in order to obtain an equivalent inequation:

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{2x - 1}{x - 1}\right| > 2 & \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{2x-1}{x-1}\right)^{2} > 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{4x^{2} - 4x  + 1}{x^{2} - 2x + 1} - 4 > 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{4x - 3}{x^{2} - 2x + 1} > 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
4x - 3 > 0\\\\
x\neq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| \frac{2x - 1}{x - 1} \right| > 2.$$

$$\implies  \frac{2x - 1}{x - 1}  > 2  \text{   } \text{or} \text{      }\frac{2x - 1}{x - 1}  < -2$$

$$\implies  \frac{2x - 1}{x - 1}  -2>0  \text{   } \text{or} \text{      }\frac{2x - 1}{x - 1} +2  < 0$$

$$\implies x\in (1,\infty) \text{   } \text{or} \text{      }x\in(0.75,1)$$

$$\implies x\in (1,\infty) \text{   } \cup \text{      }x\in(0.75,1)$$

$$\implies x\in(0.75,1)\cup(1,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

> Logically I think you could take $\frac{2x-1}{x-1}>2$ and $\frac{2x-1}{x-1}<-2$.

That is a mistake: This would be correct if you had said "or" rather than "and".

If $|a|>b$ that means $\Bigg(a>b \text{ }\underline{\text{or}}\text{ (not “and”) } a<-b\Bigg).$

The first one does not give $x\in(-\infty,+\infty).$ Here is the next mistake:
$$
\require{cancel} \xcancel{\text{If } \frac{2x-1}{x-1}>2 \text{ then } 2x-1>2(x-1).}
$$

You can multiply both sides of an inequality by the same thing if it is positive, and also if it is negative if you interchange the roles of "greater than" and "less than". But $x-1$ is positive if $x>1$ and negative if $x<1.$

One way to solve this is this:
\begin{align}
& \frac{2x-1}{x-1} > 2 \\[8pt]
& \frac{2x-1}{x-1} - 2 > 0 \\[8pt]
& \frac{2x-1}{x-1} - \frac{2x-2}{x-1} > 0 \\[8pt]
& \frac 1 {x-1}>0 \\[8pt]
& x-1>0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work. It is false that $\require{cancel}\left|\frac{2x-1}{x-1}\right|$ is both $\frac{2x-1}{x-1}$ and $-\frac{2x-1}{x-1}$; it is $\frac{2x-1}{x-1}$ when $\frac{2x-1}{x-1}\geqslant0$ and $-\frac{2x-1}{x-1}$ otherwise. Now, note that$$\frac{2x-1}{x-1}\geqslant 0\iff x\in\left(-\infty,\frac12\right]\cup(1,\infty).$$You can also solve the the problem using the fact that\begin{align}\left|\frac{2x-1}{x-1}\right|>2&\iff\left(\frac{2x-1}{x-1}\right)^2>4\\&\iff\cancel{4x^2}-4x+1\geqslant\cancel{4x^2}-8x+4\end{align}

Comment: I wish they would learn to draw pictures, at least the simpler ones https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTS2n.jpg